# Assign a char array class member using string literal

Tags: c++, arrays, class, member, chararray

If I create my class like this:

```cpp
class MyCLass {
private:
    char name[25]{};
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(char name[]);
};
```

```cpp
MyClass::MyCLass() {
    stringCopy("", this->name);
}
MyCLass::MyClass(char name[]) {
    stringCopy(name, this->name);
}
```

where `stringCopy` is a function I made to copy two char arrays, when I create in the `main` function an object `MyClass obj("John");`, the name is assigned correctly but I get the following warning: `ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'`, so I asked myself: What is the correct and best way to initialize a char array as a class member?

First of all, I don't like the way I initialized `char name[25]{};` but the only alternative would be to use dynamic memory. Is there a better alternative than the two?

Also, although the message I get after compiling the code is only a warning, I'd rather avoid such potential conflicts in my code. Is there another way to avoid this problem other than creating a char array with the name and then creating an object and passing this new variable as an argument?

EDIT: I missed that detail: I am required to use a char array. No strings are allowed.

Comment: The constructor `MyCLass::MyClass(char name[])` needs to be `MyCLass::MyClass(const char name[])`. A string literal is a `const char[]`.

Comment: In C++ for your own sanity use `std::string`. Using C strings is nothing but a mess, especially in situations like this where you have a length limit (`25`) that is not advertised anywhere, nor documented, nor easily discoverable.

Comment: If you must use character arrays, please review the `str*()` standard functions, such as `stdcpy` and `strcmp`.  Otherwise use `std::string`.

Comment: @tadman I totally agree with you but using cString is a requirement for this assignment. Also, creating my own stdcpy functions is encouraged.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That answered one of my questions. Thanks!

Comment: These "C++" courses are causing lasting damage to the industry. Sad to see they keep coming.

Comment: @tadman I actually study at one of the best universities in my country. I am not a great fan of such torture but it isn't completely useless.

Comment: Sadly the best universities are still teaching C++ material that was out of date in the early 2000s. The never have been known for being "current".

Answer (score 0):

Given the advices in the comments, you would probably go with something along:

```
class MyCLass {
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    MyClass(std::string & n = ""):name(std::move(n)){};
};
```

There is not point in using a `StringCopy()` function for this kind of copy, the functions in the standard libary do that well already ()

Comment: All of these can be resolved to a single ctor, `MyClass(std::string s = "") : name(std::move(s)) {}`